# Accessing SqlDataSource result in code behind for conversion

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid, sqldatasource

I have SqlDataSource on my ASP.NET page and load this into Telerik's RadGrid control.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="DataSource" 
    runat="server"    
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ServerConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Timestamp], [Label], [Project], [Product], [Value], [Reference] FROM [Operation]">
</asp:SqlDataSource
```

My field [Value] is a byte value representing an enum. When I load data into the grid I would like to convert these byte values into their enum equivalents, in other words I want clear text form.

I tried to do something in OnSelected and OnLoad() events of the SqlDataSource component but no success. Is there a way to access data in code behind coming from SqlDataSource before it is rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the [**`ItemDataBound`**](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-appearance-conditional-formatting.html) event of the `RadGrid` which is similar to *`RowDataBound`* event in *`GridView`*. For example:

### **ASPX:**

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="DataSource"
                 OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound" >
```

### **C# Code-Behind:**

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)     
{  
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem) // get the row collection of cells/items
    {  
        GridDataItem dataItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item; 

        // here we are converting the TEXT value to INT of the "VALUE" column

        if(int.Parse(dataItem["Value"].Text) == 1)
            dataItem["Value"].Text = "A"; // here you can set cell value as you like
    }
}
```